# Django filtering queries with multi-table inheritance

Tags: python, django

I'm using [Django multi-table inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance) to implement a notifications system.

It looks like this:

```
class Notification(models.Model):
    # this allows us to check the type without having to query another table
    type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=type_choices)
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+', null=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now)
    read = models.BooleanField(default=False)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["-date"]


# Users can comment on items.
class CommentNotification(Notification):
    comment = models.ForeignKey(Comment, related_name='+')


class ShareNotification(Notification):
    share = models.ForeignKey(Share, related_name='+')


# If user unsubscribes from an item, they will not receive notifications of comments on that item
class UnsubscribeItem(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='+')


class Comment(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item, related_name='comments')
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='+')
    comment = models.TextField()
```

If I want to get all notifications for a user, I can simply query the `Notification` table.  But I also want to exclude any `CommentNotification` entries if the user has unsubscribed from that item (only if there is an `UnsubscribeItem` with `user=request.user` and `item=comment.item`).

The problem of course is the field I want to filter is not on the base class.  Is it possible to modify the queryset itself to exclude those entries?  Or do I need to exclude them while serializing the collection? (I'm using django-rest-framework to serialize for my API, if that helps.)

Comment: Is there a reason why unread `CommentNotification`s are not purged from the database when a user unsubscribes from an item?

Comment: Going along that line of thought, perhaps this would be better solved on the inbound side. When a comment is added, do not add `CommentNotification`s for users who have unsubscribed.

Comment: I would do that anyway, but you may also need the purge. Consider the scenario: User subscribes, comments are posted, comment notifications are created. User unsubscribes. What happens to existing notifications for the unsubscribed item? Are they marked *read*? Are they removed? Or do they simply stick around?